# Possible reasons for the need of an XML element Sequence in ReST Service

Tags: .net, xml, rest

I'm trying to understand ReST and XML a little more - A third party company has asked if we're ok with their service accepting requesting xml elements in a specific order. This causes a problem for us as we are using objects that have an inheritance hierarchy (so can't use  etc as .Net serializes objects recursively).

I know I can use the [IXmlSerializable Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) (much more work for us) to control serialization, or create individual objects for each request (not very elegant). But wanted to avoid changing anything we already have as it is very maintainable at the moment.

I wondered what possible reasons there are for requiring XML elements in a specific order, (it seems a bit of a bad design decision), and any reasons why not to order xml elements explicitly (other than the obvious point of reducing maintainability when they want to add an element).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical reason for requiring XML elements in order is that whatever is processing the XML is maintaining state while it's doing so.  It's getting information from the `foo` element that is then used when processing the `bar` element, and so on.

You might say, "well, then process the `foo` element first, and then process the `bar` element, and don't rely on the document order."  Which is all well and good if the process deserializes the stream of XML before you process it.  But if the receiving process is using an `XmlReader`, or SAX, it's combining parsing and processing into a single step, most commonly to maximize performance and minimize memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very general question – but an answer might be that having a specified ordering in an XML format probably matters most when human beings experience that format and/or when there innate ordering to what is being represented.

So XHTML 1.0 (for example) has a basic ordering of <head> and <body> elements within the <html> document element, and this corresponds to our normal understanding of documents having titling and metadata information before the bulk of the text. Within XHTML a table (for example) has an ordering (broadly) of table metric information followed by rows, each of which contains a sequence of cells. Allowing the order to differ here would make what is already complex, unpredictable and nearly impossible to deal with.

However, within XHTML's <head> element there is no set ordering for occurrences of the <script>, <style>, <meta>, <link> or <object> elements. So you have both styles in evidence within this one language.

So having a set ordering for an XML format is by no means necessarily a "bad design decision" but can be evidence of *good* design.

Comment: Sorry if it sounds too general, I was hoping someone would list a number of reasons for requiring XML to be in a specific order. I wasn't saying it was a bad design decision, just that it sounded like one as I couldn't think of any good reasons for doing so. +1 for your html example, however this is a ReST Service, dealing with objects, so I'm don't think the answer (while valid) applies to this question.